# Elasticsearch change sharding key

Tags: elasticsearch, key, sharding

I'd like to know if it's possible to choose the sharding key of an elasticsearch index.

Instead of using the _id field of my documents, I'd like to be able to specify another field on which to base the sharding.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `routing` key probably. Check the [docs on sharding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html) for more details

Comment: Cool. But be aware of using `_path`, as its deprecated since 1.5.0.